# postgres processes running while not using it

Tags: background-process, postgresql, start-stop-daemon

as in the object of the discussion thread I have the following situation: all time I start my linux OS, I check processes running with the top command in bash and I always find 7-8 postgres processes running. Why so? Are they daemon that start at the OS start? Should I deactivate them for better resource usage? And in which way can I stop definitevely them? And how can I reactivate them in future ? Thanks

[image: top command]

Comment: It's probably starting on boot. What distro and version of linux are you using?

Comment: If it's Ubuntu 16.04 try `sudo systemctl disable postgres` then restart and try `top` again.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. In a future postgres applicatio should I restart the service?

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `postgres` via upstart:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/postgres.override
```

Based on this [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/a/19324/135947) *(shows methods for both systemD and upstart, if you have Ubuntu 14.04 you should have upstart)*.